# RSS Feed for TAGS with invalid content URLS

Tags: sef, tags, rss

i used joomla on https://www.724press.com and after one year i cant solve one important problem of it.

my website language is PERSIAN. its magazine website so, i need rss feed for many TAGS of Article. basic RSS url for Article Section is normal and work fine. but RSS Feed which joomla makes for Article TAGS have invalid URLS for content which reason of many 404 error in google webmaster.

**for example:**

**TAG:** Windows 10

**URL:** https://www.724press.com/tag/windows-10

**URL of RSS Feed:** 724press.com/tag/windows-10?format=feed&type=rss

if you open feed you can see my problem. for example about this article:

correct url of a sample article is :

724press.com/science/8597-%D8%AA%D8%BA%DB%8C%DB%8C%D8%B1-layout-%D8%B5%D9%81%D8%AD%D9%87-%DA%A9%D9%84%DB%8C%D8%AF-%D9%88%DB%8C%D9%86%D8%AF%D9%88%D8%B2-10

and invalid url of that article in rss feed is :

724press.com/%3Fid%3D8591%3A%D8%A7%D8%B6%D8%A7%D9%81%D9%87-%DA%A9%D8%B1%D8%AF%D9%86-%D8%AC%DB%8C%D9%85%DB%8C%D9%84-%DA%A9%D9%88%D8%B1%D8%AA%D8%A7%D9%86%D8%A7-%D9%88%DB%8C%D9%86%D8%AF%D9%88%D8%B2-%DB%B1%DB%B0

appearance of both link has been broken by Persian characters in Alias, so for better understanding of the difference between the two links, I removed Alias Charechters from both links:

**Correct:** 724press.com/science/8597-

**inCorrect:** 724press.com/%3Fid%3D8591%3A

you can see SECTION in first url, but in second url you cant see it. it seem joomla cant use SEF URL for article url in TAG feed.

You can use this site for decode charechters of second (invalid) url:

url-encode-decode.com

so :

%3Fid%3D **=** ?id=

%3A **=** :

and it want show url with this Structure: *724press.com/?id=8591:ALIAS*

but it seem it cant decode few string of url even for non-SEF URL

This issue is not for current release of joomla and we have it from earlier version and on many sites.

anyone have a solution for it?

Thank you

Comment: This page appears to be abandoned.  Did you manage to resolve this issue? Did you end up using Ron's suggestion? Please progress this page to a system recognised resolution.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use other extensions to generate your feeds?

I think the most popular one of that type extension is obRSS.

Comment: Hi, Yes i know obRSS is better for this goal. but i want find a way to solve this bug in main core of joomla.

Comment: I know the solution from developers of Joomla team is better. But while waiting they support it, I chose using third party extensions. Whatever, that is only my suggestion :").

Comment: Yes Ron, thats good Alternative solution. Thank you for it :-)

Comment: You are welcome :")! Did you try to use it? Hope it worked!